Ambiguity in the formula for dispersion measure in linked paper
The following paper (open access) https://doi.org/10.1051/0004-6361/202347139  has its first formula define the dispersion measure as follows: $$DM=\int_{0}^{z} \frac{n_e(z)}{(1+z)}dl$$
where $n_e$ is the electron density. It is given as a function of the redshift $z$, but I think it should be given as a function of the distance along the line of sight. Otherwise, how can the integral be correct? Is this a mistake in the notation of the paper? Specifically, should the $(1+z)$ in the denominator be something like (1+redshift) instead?

Specifically, should the $(1+z)$ in the denominator be something like (1+redshift) instead? If $z$ is the redshift (common notation I'm used to, at least), how is your proposal different from what is already used in the paper?

What I'm asking is whether the notation is incorrect - the integration, as far as I can tell, is from 0 (the observer) to $z$ (the straight line distance to the source). The electron density is given as a function of $z$, which I assume is a function of distance. The denominator is $(1+z)$ - should this $z$ be the redshift? Or is the electron density a function of redshift and not the distance?

The authors state $n_e$ is the electron density at redshift z, so I don't know any other way to interpret what is written: $z$ is clearly indicated as the redshift and $n_e$ a function of the redshift.

@KyleKanos - I am guessing the OP is missing the subtle point that z is a type of normalized length scale.

@honeste_vivere Yes, that's probably what I'm missing. I still don't quite understand it, can you elaborate?

The redshift is a measure of distance away from the observation point.  I think the Wikipedia page on this is likely a good start for introductory info.
